# Crear trigger para insertar dato en oracle

Tags: oracle, trigger

estoy empezando con oracle y necesito crear un trigger para insertar unos datos en una tabla a la hora de hacer un update, tengo la tabla creada y el siguiente trigger:

```
    create or replace trigger modificaciones_salario before
    update of salario on empleados
    for each row
    declare
    id_empleados number;
    hora varchar2;
    begin
    select id_empleado into id from empleados_pac where :new.salario=salario;
    select to_char(sysdate, 'HH24:MI:SS')into hora1 from dual;
    insert into audita_salarios 
    (id_empleado,salario_antiguo,salario_nuevo,fecha,hora,username)
    values (id,:old.salario,:new.salario,sysdate,hora1,user);
    end;
    /
```

Pero a la hora de ejecutarlo me lanza el error de que la tabla no existe, le he dado todos los permisos al usuario y fuera del trigger si que me permite hacer inserts y selects de la tabla no se que puede estar pasando.
Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Hola, ¿podrías copiar el código en texto a la página? Siempre es mejor que poner una captura.

Comment: Gracias ya lo he modificado

Answer (score 0):

Arriba en la declaración es on empleados_pac

Comment: Puedes añadir una explicación a por qué crees que esa es la solución.